# Using 'before' with specific time

Tags: grammar

Is it ok to say:
I take the pill before 2 hours of meal
Or I have to say:
I take the pill 2 hours before the meal.

Answer (score 1):

"2 hours before a meal".

Or if you are taking pills regularly, you may say "I take one pill 2 hours before each meal".